# TensorFlow in_top_k evaluation input argumants

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the tutorial in [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) and trying to change the evaluation method for the model (at the bottom). I would like to get a top-5 evaluation and I'm trying to use to following code:

```
topFiver=tf.nn.in_top_k(y, y_, 5, name=None)
```

However, this yields the following error:

```
File "AlexNet.py", line 111, in <module>
    topFiver = tf.nn.in_top_k(pred, y, 5, name=None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 346, in in_top_k
    targets=targets, k=k, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 486, in apply_op
    _Attr(op_def, input_arg.type_attr))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 59, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: DataType float32 for attr 'T' not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is that `tf.nn.in_top_k()` only works for `tf.int32` or `tf.int64` data, but my data is in `tf.float32` format. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `targets` argument to [`tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions, targets, k)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#in_top_k) must be a vector of class IDs (i.e. indices of columns in the `predictions` matrix). This means that it only works for single-class classification problems.

If your problem is a single-class problem, then I assume that your `y_` tensor is a one-hot encoding of the true labels for your examples (for example because you also pass them to an op like [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits). In that case, you have two options:

- If the labels were originally stored as integer labels, pass them directly to `tf.nn.in_top_k()` without converting them to one-hot. (Also, consider using [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) as your loss function, because it may be more efficient.)
- If the labels were originally stored in the one-hot format, you can convert them to integers using `tf.argmax()`:

  ```
  labels = tf.argmax(y_, 1)
  topFiver = tf.nn.in_top_k(y, labels, 5)
  ```

Comment: do you know what accuracy metric should be used if the problem is multi-class?