# Text Classification for multiple label

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, text-classification

I doing Text Classification by Convolution Neural Network. I used health documents (ICD-9-CM code) for my project and I used the same model as [dennybritz](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/) used but my data has 36 labels. I used one_hot encoding to encode my label.

Here is my problem, when I run data which has one label for each document my code the accuracy is perfect from 0.8 to 1. If I run data which has more than one labels, the accuracy is significantly reduced.

For example: a document has single label as `"782.0"`: `[0 0 1 0 ... 0]`,
a document has multiple label as `"782.0 V13.09 593.5"`: `[1 0 1 0 ... 1]`.

Could anyone suggest why this happen and how to improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The label encoding seems correct. If you have multiple correct labels, `[1 0 1 0 ... 1]` looks totally fine. The loss function used in Denny's [post](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/) is `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`, which is the loss function for a multi-class problem.

> Computes softmax cross entropy between logits and labels.
>
> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in
>   which the classes are **mutually exclusive** (each entry is in exactly one class).

In multi-label problem, you should use `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`:

> Computes sigmoid cross entropy given logits.
>
> Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in which each class is independent and not mutually exclusive. For instance, one could perform multilabel classification where a picture can contain both an elephant and a dog at the same time.

The input to the loss function would be logits (`WX`) and targets (labels).

#### Fix the accuracy measure

In order to measure the accuracy correctly for a multi-label problem, the code below needs to be changed.

```
# Calculate Accuracy
with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_predictions = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1))
    self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")
```

The logic of `correct_predictions` above is incorrect when you could have multiple correct labels. For example, say `num_classes=4`, and label 0 and 2 are correct. Thus your `input_y=[1, 0, 1, 0].` The `correct_predictions` would need to break tie between index 0 and index 2. I am not sure how `tf.argmax` breaks tie but if it breaks the tie by choosing the smaller index, a prediction of label 2 is always considered wrong, which definitely hurt your accuracy measure.

Actually in a multi-label problem, [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) are better metrics than accuracy. Also you can consider using precision@k (`tf.nn.in_top_k`) to report classifier performance.

Comment: Thanks greeness, I still don't understand what is the input of `logloss` function, what is `act` and `pred`.

Comment: The loss function in the blog is actually correct. But the accuracy measure needs to be changed and I suggest you to use precision/recall instead of accuracy.

Comment: Hi greeness, I tried to use both `tf.nn.top_k()` and `tf.nn.in_top_k'. But I have trouble in passing argument . When I put `tf.nn.top_k(self.scores, 2)` . The program sent error `TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type int64 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.` in the line `l2_reg_lambda=l2_reg_lambda`. Could you suggest how to use both functions ?

Comment: Thanks, according to the post `tf.nn.in_top_k(y, tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_, 1), "int32"), 1)`. I change y to "self.scores", how about "y_"

Comment: This explains the usage of targets. Hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080445/tensorflow-in-top-k-evaluation-input-argumants

Comment: Thanks you so much, I will try

Comment: It helps if you can post all your code here or give a link.

Comment: Thank you so much Greeness. This is the [training file](https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/Convect_text_classification.ipynb), [dataset(https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/2007ChallengeTrainData.xml),
 [CNN file](https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/text_cnn.py), and the 
[load file](https://github.com/ngoduyvu/Convolution-text-classification/blob/master/load_data.py).

Comment: In the training file I am setting take single label you can change it back to take multi-label by set `y = label_encoding(labels, False) ` is `True`.